# Scanf program access denied

Tags: c, scanf

I have this simple program that ask's your age.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  int age;
  printf("How old are you?\n");

  scanf("%d", &age);
  return 0;
}
```

But when I try to run it on Windows it says **Access Denied** then my Norton anti-virus kicks in saying that a threat was solved, and that same threat has the name of my program.

If I compile and run any other programs that do not have `scanf` in it everything works as expected.

I have the MinGW compiler.

Comment: Hmm.. are you outputting the exe for this anywhere different than the exe's for the other programs?  Is your makefile for this the problem?

Comment: @MartinJames all the other exe's work fine, it's just the sanf ones.

Comment: I mean, 'Hello World' is more offensive than this:)  It has to be a path issue?

Comment: That's just weird:(

Comment: Looks like you have a broken standard library implementation - do you get this on any other systems?

Comment: @TobySpeight just Windows I have a Xubuntu-VM and It works just fine.

Comment: @P.P. what should I use as a scanf replacement?

Comment: Submit the .exe file to https://www.virustotal.com/ and let us know what they report.

Comment: @MichaelWalz virustotal says it's clean but Norton detects a virus called "Heur.AdvML.B" [norton  Link](https://www.symantec.com/security_response/sape/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a false positive.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your MinGW compiler's library has some hidden code which trys to access some vital information from your computer. Seems like malware is being introduced in your library. Un install your MinGW and install it from a trusted site.

Comment: Do u have a compiler suggestion or website? So I don't mess up again.

Comment: Web site which must be secured and trusted. Do not down load from piratebay.

Comment: If you're installing binaries, you should be verifying the signature (as all reasonable package managers do).  So there's no need for the *site* to be secured, just that the *package* you install is verifiably the correct one.